# Google Vision API: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-vision

I've been testing an application example using Google Vision API.

I have the code from their github, and created the relevant project and credentials file (something Google Cloud requests) and tried to run the code.

I get the following:

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I've tried to add the relevant SSL certificates to my JRE's cacerts, I've restarted eclipse and an admin, but I still get this.

***EDIT***
I've also tried to manually set the ssl properties as follows:

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/path/to/cacerts");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","cacerts_pass");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/path/to/cacerts");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","cacerts_pass");
```

Any ideas to resolve this issue, please?

If there's anything I should provide, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to set properties javax.net.ssl.trustStore ,javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword and check

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana I've googled it and found how to do that. But the issue is still the same

Comment: Either you set the property in program System.setProperty(name,value) or pass it as argument to -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="c:\pathtofile"

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana See edited question please

Comment: Can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c to see what is happening

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana done. still the same

Comment: what is that you see when you have -Djavax.net.debug=all

Comment: there's alot of output...what should I see?

Comment: can you paste it in chat

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html look here for different steps this might help you to understand flow

Comment: My company's security policy won't let me start a chat in here...but bottom line is SSLHandShakeException I get at the end

Comment: i think you can paste all the contents here in comment

Comment: when you try to connect to endpoint using webbrowser do you get a endpoint untrusted message

Comment: I cant paste it in the question due to length limit.

Comment: No, I don't. I connect fine

Comment: Because if you have "SSL scanning" enabled in antivirus sometime you see this behaviour

Comment: I don't have any control over the AntiVirus. do you suggest that's because of that?

Comment: If you have "SSL scanning" in antivirus https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html

Comment: We can look into the ssl debug and then conclude..

Comment: via command line I've successfully connected. not via eclipse

Comment: Then antivirus is not a problem.

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana are you famiiiar with response "This is not a P3P policy"?

Comment: I have no idea but found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048306/what-is-the-most-broad-p3p-header-that-will-work-with-ie