# P3P Header Info in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, http-headers

I'm not sure where I'm suppose to put this in my Asp.net MVC website:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("P3P", "CP=\\\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\\\"");
```

I put it in the:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("P3P", "CP=\\\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\\\"");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Account", action = "Logon", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );

}
```

But I get back

> Response is not available in this context.

Anyone know where I am suppose to put this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can put it in the web.config:

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="P3P" value='CP="CAO PSA OUR"'/>
```

This way you do not need to put it in the code.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5258105/419956) for details on what the `value` means.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me from an eternity of pointless debugging.

Comment: @vtortola: Thanks! This was driving me crazy.  Great solution.

Comment: P3P header is not supported by any modern browser in 2020 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want this header on every response, something like this should do it

```
public class P3PHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("P3P", "CP=\\\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\\\"");

    }
}
```

then add the filter to the global collection

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new P3PHeaderAttribute());
    }
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for but I already used the web.config change. I upvoted you, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class that inherits `ActionFilter` and overrides `OnResultExecuting()` to add that header.

Then, add it to the global filters collection.