# Unable to get session in IE and safari

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, safari

I've created a website in which user add his stuff and publish it. After publish my website generates a script which user should copy in his/her website. That code first make a cross-domain ajax request with jsonp. If everything works fine then an iframe gets created by my script and a session with that user's id is created and using that session value i fetch that user's data. This works completely fine in `chrome` and `firefox`. But not in `IE` or `Safari`.

I tried to `print_r($_SESSION)` on the page. In chrome and firefox i can see the vaue of my session but in IE and safari it displays `Array()`.

I cannot understand what is the problem. Please tell me what should i do.

My IE version is 11.0 and safari's version is 5.1.7 for windows.

Comment: You need to post your code, do you expect us to use telepathy to figure out what you're doing wrong?

Comment: @Barmar What code i add. I simply put  `$_SESSION['customer_id'] = $result['customer_id']` to set session so i did't mentioned my code.

Comment: Do you call `session_start()`? Do you make sure that there's no output before doing this? Check the PHP error log for the warning "Headers already sent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include this header in your PHP file which is used for cross-domain request.

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

For further explanation, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257983/what-is-headerp3p-cp-cao-psa-our)

Comment: Thanks It started working in `IE` but not in `safari`

Comment: add these headers too and see if they work: 

header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

Comment: try this: http://www.superiorwebsys.com/114-php-session-in-iframe-in-safari-and-other-browsers/